# Alternatives to fix PowerShell error "execution of scripts is disabled on this system"

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script which is written by me. I try to run the PowerShell script as below;

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>c:\test\Test.ps1
```

So this is giving me an error saying:

> File c:\test\Test.ps1  cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.

I found that setting `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` will fix the error.

But my questions are;

1. What is this signing is about?
2. Can we fix this error without setting `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` (doing a signing kind of a thing)? If so, how to do that?
3. Is there a security issue arise if I set `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in my web server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Set-ExecutionPolicy` causes a system wide change. Scripts are possible security vulnerabilities, which is why all script execution is disabled by default. One possibility is to launch the PowerShell process from the command line with an execution policy that is only in effect for that specific session. The command line would be something like:

```
> powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "c:\test\Test.ps1"
```

You could combine this with signing by leaving the default policy to Restricted and launching PowerShell with RemoteSigned or AllSigned policy when needed. Some additional information on the powershell.exe command line options is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx).

Comment: Set-ExecutionPolicy can be restricted by user too with **-Scope CurrentUser**, now the local user does not need to redo the change. Anyway your demonstrating perfectly how the default execution policy does not do anything meaningful. You can easily just put all your powershell inside a batch file and that then always execute, it is as good a attack vector as running the ps1 file. So there's really no use for this default policy its just stupid, if it would actually block attacks then yes sure good setting, but it does not. Its jut annoyingly stupid.

Comment: Not only does this take care of the signing problem, it also takes care of the problem of the file type opening in notepad by default.  Excellent!

Answer (score 3):

If you did what the instructions told you to do you would have gotten a help page that would have told you exactly what you need to do.

```
get-help about_signing
```

In summary, the computer has no way to tell that whoever wrote the script was a trustworthy person, so by default it does not run any untrustworthy scripts. The two ways to fix this is either allow scripts from unknown sources (the solution you found out about by using `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`) or by "[signing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing)" the script proving it came from a trustworthy source and has not been tampered with seance you got it from that source.

To sign your own code you will need a code signing certificate. Read that `about_signing` help and there is a section called `CREATE A SELF-SIGNED CERTIFICATE` that tells you how to do it.

After you have the certificate you need to sign your script. If you check that same help again there is a section called `SIGN A SCRIPT` that tells you how to do that too.

Comment: Thanks for the cleared information you provided. Singing code I is fit to my issue. But I haven't done that before. Felt like lengthy process. So I chose the solution suggested `mike z`. Thanks for the details you provided.